# How can I decode PDU with GSMComm or PduBitPacker?

Tags: c#, sms, decode, gsm, pdu

I want to Decode PDU Text Retrieved from GSM Modem in C#, How can I decode it with **GSMComm** or **PduBitPacker**?

Please answer me with a code

TY

(P.S. I have encoded text and I do not need to get it from Modem)

Comment: Read the documentation for both.  In the FAQ of GSMComm, it tells you how to receive a raw PDU, and in the documentation for PduBitPacker it explains how to use it to unpack a PDU.  PduBitPacker appears to work only for GSM 7 bit alphabet though, so you would have to adapt it if you want to use a language that can't be sent in the 7 bit alphabet.

Comment: I've tested _PduBitPacker_, but the unpacked string is different from sms message.

Comment: @SList I didn't understand your way for GSMComm. I created a ShortMessageFromPhone object with my data but how can I convert it to DecodedShortMessage?

Comment: You can get a raw PDU (not a decoded message) from GSMComm, that you can feed into PduBitPacker.  What is the text of your test SMS, is it all GSM 7-bit characters (for example numbers or english)?

Comment: My Full Encoded Text is: 0791893905004100640C9189398978168400003160915151238110050003110202 **C26735B94D87DF41**
highlighted ones are original text encoded. others are headers and...

My Original Text is "agjdmtpw"

Look at this site, what's the algorithm behind it? [Online SMS PDU Decoder/Converter](http://www.diafaan.com/sms-tutorials/gsm-modem-tutorial/online-sms-pdu-decoder/)

Comment: The algorithm behind it is the SMS PDU definition in 3GPP specification 27.005 at http://www.3gpp.org/ftp/Specs/html-info/27005.htm. Look at section 2.5.2.6 Short Message Data.

Comment: @SList :> I couldn't find Short Message Data Section

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you include PDUConverter.dll in your project.

```
IncomingSmsPdu sms = IncomingSmsPdu.Decode("0791893905004100640C9189398978168400003160915151238110050003110202C26735B94D87DF41", true);

Console.WriteLine(sms.UserDataText);
```

The first argument of Decode is your RAW PDU string including header at the end, the second argument is a flag telling the decoder that a header is present.

Inside of UserDataText you will find the SMS text.

If you see estrange characters at the beginning, it is because you have a "Smart Message", that is, a multi-part SMS that should be concatenated into a single large message, this is a trick invented by Nokia.

The class *GsmComm.PduConverter.SmartMessaging.SmartMessageDecoder* could be of help if you want to deal with this smart messaging thing.