# Read long sms from modem

Tags: c#, sms, gsmcomm

I read some SMS from the modem (by AT command). I use gsmcomm library. I save read SMS as a string. But gsmcomm work with List of smsPDU.. I have some code- where SMS reading from device (not in a string). How convert my string to List? or add to List?

```
//I read sms with string
string input = ExecCommand("AT+CMGL=\"ALL\"", 5000, "Failed to read the messages.");
```

```
//other code with read long sms where read from device (not AT command)
List<string> messagesList = new List<messageList>();
List<SmsPdu> multiPartMsg = new List<SmsPdu>();


foreach (var i in modem.ReadMessages(PhoneMessageStatus.All, PhoneStorageType.Phone))
{
    string msg;

    if (SmartMessageDecoder.IsPartOfConcatMessage(((SmsDeliverPdu)i.Data)))
    {

        multiPartMsg.Add(i.Data);
        try
        {
            if (SmartMessageDecoder.AreAllConcatPartsPresent(multiPartMsg))
            {

                msg= SmartMessageDecoder.CombineConcatMessageText(multiPartMsg);
                messagesList.Add(msg);
                multiPartMsg.Clear();


            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {}


    }
    else
    {
        msg = ((SmsDeliverPdu)i.Data).UserDataText;
        messagesList.Add(msg);

    }
}
```

Help me, please.

Comment: Fir change to : List<string> messagesList = new List<string>();  the use : foreach(string message in messageList){ string newMessage = string.Format("AT+CMGL=\"{0}\"", message); messageList.Add(newMessage); }

Comment: sorry but i understand. ```string input = ExecCommand("AT+CMGL=\"ALL\"", 5000, "Failed to read the messages.");
                
                List<string> messagesList = new List<string>();
                List<SmsPdu> multiPartMsg = new List<SmsPdu>();

                foreach (string message in messagesList)
                {
                    string newMessage = string.Format("AT+CMGL=\"{0}\"", input);
                    messagesList.Add(newMessage);
                }```  message and messageList is empty..

Comment: What messages are you sending?  I assumed messageList already contained the messages you were going to send.

Comment: no no. I read sms from modem! I want read long sms.  i see this [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17249911/how-can-i-decode-pdu-with-gsmcomm-or-pdubitpacker/56888938?noredirect=1#comment100326789_56888938) and not undastad how it read.